# Rewrite Rule translate from Lighttpd Regex to NginX

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting, lighttpd

Not quite sure where to start from here.  I have this rewrite rule that we used for our apps using lighttpd and we're contemplating of moving the web server to NginX for standardization.

Lighttpd config line inside the lighttpd.conf:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
 ".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
 "^/js/.*$" => "$0",
 "^.*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf |jar|class)$" => "$0",
 "" => "/index.php"
 )
```

First, can anyone help me translate those lines?  I inherit it from someone else and have no idea what that means?

Next, How do I convert those lines to usable configuration line in NginX?  I'm not even sure what to provide to you all to help with understanding the line.  All I know is that when we remove those lines from lighttpd, the apps stop working.  I have our NginX working on a standard Php with Php-fpm on centos 6.4.  when I use the phpinfo file, NginX was able to generate the info but when we installed the apps it errored with this error inside the error log file.

```
2013/08/12 21:51:00 [error] 18844#0: *16 open() "/var/www/html/myapps/public/user/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.8.100, server: _, request: "GET /user/login HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.8.215"
```

and on the web browser I got "**404 not found**" error.

Also for consistency, can anyone suggest how to translate this line?

```
location / { if ( $uri !~ ^/(index\.php|css|images|core|uploads|js|robots\.txt) ) { rewrite ^ /index.php last; } }
```

Please advise on additional information I can provide to help with the translation?  I wasn't even sure whether this is an NginX problem or apps problem.  Many thanks in advance for all of your help.

Comment: If I understood that last line correctly, you are trying to exclude some folders and files from the rewrite, this is already handled in my answer using `try_files` because if a certain file already exists nginx will server the actual file first, if it doesn't exist it would be rewritten to the `index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know much about lighttpd configs, you'll need to explain to me so i could write them in nginx format.

Also I don't know what will process the PHP, is it fast-cgi or fpm, or what ?

```
server {
    server_name example.com; #replace with your domain name
    index index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
    }
    location ~* \.php$ {
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad.  It's fpm that will process the PHP and I dont' even know how to explain it to you other than I need a way to redirect some of the code in the controller but beyond that I'm completely blind.

Comment: check `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` look for a line that says `listen`, does it have a sock file, or a port 9000 ?

Comment: which works for you `example.com/index.php/user/login` work or `example.com/index.php?/user/login` ? ( replace `example.com` with your domain )

Comment: Thanks Mohammad.  This one works for me.  example.com/user/login.  This has always been the way it works for the main page.  So the webbrowser is pointed to the /public directory where the index.php is in it then it redirect the apps to example.com/user/login.  AM I making any sense?

Comment: BTW, I tried your line Mohammad and this is what I got.

2013/08/12 22:54:03 [error] 19396#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php/user/login", client: 192.168.8.100, server: 192.168.8.215, request: "GET /user/login HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.8.215"

It actually should just redirect it to example.com/user/login only.

Comment: Anyone else with suggestion?  Please help?

Comment: well my other suggestion would be trying `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;` instead, when i asked about the 2 URL's I meant on the old system, just to know how the `index.php` works, some frameworks use the uri and some use the args ( which is the 2nd suggestion i just mentioned in this comment )

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for the serious follow up.  That kind of solve the problem.  I can load the application now with no error just slower that lighttpd which is a bit of a dissappointment but that's not your problem.  Thanks for all the input....  :-)

Comment: did the old app (lighttpd) also use fpm ? is nginx the only change you did ?

Comment: BTW in the name of consistency with my lighttpd, I'm wondering whether anyone can help me translate this into a working line for NginX since it looks similar to our config at Lighttpd?

[code]    location /  {
    if ( $uri !~ ^/(index\.php|css|images|core|uploads|js|robots\.txt) ) {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
       }
   }
[/code]

Comment: add it to your question and ill reply on my answer

Comment: Thank you and I added the question per your request.  Many thanks.